# MySQL - Select rows where json_column has specific value

Tags: mysql, json

I have a MySQL table **test** with a column **trip_info** that contains JSON, for example:

```
{
    "trips": [{
        "id": "261213_0",
        "type": "CD",
        "truck": "1847",
        "planbloc": "EE_001",
        "reuse": "EE_001",
        "status": "4",
        "stops": [{
            "208201": [{
                "handling": "S",
                "date": "2021-07-16"
            }],
            "D_517318_SZENTGOTTHARD": [{
                "handling": "S",
                "date": "2021-07-16"
            }],
            "T_857925_LOIPERSDORF - KITZLADEN": [{
                "handling": "C",
                "date": "2021-07-16"
            }],
            "T_895103_OBERWART": [{
                "handling": "C",
                "date": "2021-07-16"
            }],
            "D_613251_SCHACHENDORF": [{
                "handling": "S",
                "date": "2021-07-16"
            }],
            "T_894297_SZIGETSZENTMIKLOS": [{
                "handling": "D",
                "date": "2021-07-19"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

I would like to select all rows in my table that contain a stop id '208201' with handling 'C'. I tried the following query without success:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(trip_info, '"208201"', '$.trips.stops') AND JSON_CONTAINS(trip_info, '"C"', '$.trips.stops.handling')
```

Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 0):

Try below queries:

### MySQL v5.7

```
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_UNQUOTE(trip_info->"$.trips[*].stops[*].""208201""[*].handling"), '"C"');
```

Check [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sFpApdHApKPGFyAbLPhBc5/2)

### MariaDB v10.3

```
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(trip_info, "$.trips[*].stops[*].""208201""[*].handling")), '"C"');
```

Comment: thank you for your help. Unfortunately, this didn't gave any results. Please see this screenshot:

https://westeurope1-mediap.svc.ms/transform/thumbnail?provider=spo&inputFormat=png&cs=fFNQTw&docid=https%3A%2F%2Fewals-my.sharepoint.com%3A443%2F_api%2Fv2.0%2Fdrives%2Fb!bdXvSJdR7EubrND1YGNN2mcQ0Cl8XTJPg3i9zLpVkdAjJhSfAI8BQLveqFSIGyJt%2Fitems%2F017P7A6D2GLWNHVK6L7BDZHNGFXGM2QAB2%3Fversion%3DPublished&encodeFailures=1&ctag=%22c%3A%7B7A9A5D46-CBAB-47F8-93B4-C5B999A8003A%7D%2C1%22&width=1920&height=893&srcWidth=&srcHeight="

Comment: Have you got a chance to check your data? Does it have any row where value of handling is C for stop id 208201? Please check your data once. Or You can execute the queries provided by me in the dbfiddle.

Comment: i see the screenshot link is not working, so I have uploaded it again to another host:
https://snipboard.io/osMhKF.jpg

All the data is in there :) Your dbfiddle seems to work, but not my query.
Please note I am using MariaDB v10.3 and JSON functions are supported.

Comment: I have added query for MariaDB v10.3 in the answer. I have tested same query on my machine. Its working for me as expected. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi @Laurents_Gits, Did you got chance to test new query?